# Difference between reassignment and reopen with Ruby IO streams

Tags: ruby, io, stdout, variable-assignment

In Ruby, what is the difference between reassigning an IO stream and using the `IO#reopen` method? In other words, what is the difference between

```
$stdout = newfile
```

and:

```
$stdout.reopen(newfile)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So basically reopen will associates `$stdout` with the `newfile` stream => `$stdout` and `newfile` will be two File instances associated to the same stream.

`=` will actually assign the `newfile` File instance to `$stdout` => `$stdout` and `newfile` will be two variables pointing to the same File instance.

Consequences:

When using `reopen` any change on the instance (that does not affect the stream itself) won't be reflected in the other instance.

`=` Example:

```
a = File.new('name')
b = File.new('name')

a.lineno #=> 0
b.lineno #=> 0

a.lineno = 3

a.lineno #=> 3
b.lineno #=> 0

b = a 

a.lineno #=> 3
b.lineno #=> 3

a.lineno = 0

a.lineno #=> 0
b.lineno #=> 0
```

`reopen` example:

```
a = File.new('name')
b = File.new('name')

a.lineno #=> 0
b.lineno #=> 0

a.lineno = 3

a.lineno #=> 3
b.lineno #=> 0

b.reopen(a)

a.lineno #=> 3
b.lineno #=> 3

a.lineno = 0

a.lineno #=> 0
b.lineno #=> 3
```

Comment: As a followup, how does the `sync` option work with these two ways of stream redirection?

Comment: @jrdioko The `sync` will just write to the file every time you call a write method over the `File` instance. Both, the `reopen` and the `=` will "copy" the `sync` value to the target `File` instance. Going to the point: Using the `=` you will be handling the same `File` in both variables so the stream pointer will be updated on both every time you write in any of both. Using `reopen` will let you write in one of them without modify the other's position so, if you then write to the other one, you will end up overwriting the previous content.

Answer (score 0):

Previous IO is flushed and closed in the latter (`reopen`) case I believe.

**Added:** Compare output of:

```
$stdout.write("Buffered")
$stdout = $stderr
$stdout.write("After assignment")
```

and

```
$stdout.write("Buffered")
$stdout.reopen($stderr)
$stdout.write("After reopen")
```

(best way to compare is by redirecting output using pipe)

Answer (score 0):

The difference is important when you're running child processes.

**Assignment:**

```
$stdout = File.open("/dev/null", "w")
system "ls"
warn $stdout.fileno  # file descriptor number
```

Output - notice how the `system`'s output still appeared:

```
1.txt 2.txt
7
```

**Reopening:**

```
$stdout.reopen("/dev/null")
system "ls"
warn $stdout.fileno
```

Output - the `system` output was sent to `/dev/null`:

```
1
```

**Summary:**

Reassignment of `$stdout`, `$stdin`, or `$stderr` only affects the current ruby process. A child process will write its own standard output to file descriptor (FD) 1, read standard input from FD 0, and write diagnostic output to FD 2.

If you want the child to inherit the change, you need to reopen the stream, because that reuses the file descriptor. Note a child is only affected if you `reopen` *before* starting the child.

One use case: you're writing a daemon script (or other script that needs to keep running after you've logged out). The best practice is to reopen all 3 standard streams to `/dev/null`, otherwise you might get a broken pipe if the script or child process tries to use the streams.